# How to download a file with phantomJS using Robot Framework?

Tags: phantomjs, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework with PhantomJS (headless browser) and want to download a file. But PhantomJS is not having any desired Capabilities or options to set the preferences as we do in Chrome. Looking for any suggestions or other options to download a CSV file using PhantomJS with Robot Framework.

Comment: Any reason you prefer PhantomJS over Chrome for headless browser execution? As of Chrome version 59 there is Mac and Linux support and Windows was added in version 60. Current version is 62.

Comment: i never tried chrome headless browser, PhantomJS using as I have to run this code on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you highlighted that downloading files is not the issue. Below you'll find an example of Robot Script that starts Chrome in Headless mode.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Headless Chrome - Open Browser
    ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${prefs}    Create Dictionary   credentials_enable_service=${false}                 # Verberg de sla wachtwoord op pop-up

    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    start-maximized                 # Open de browser in gemaximaliseerd.
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu    
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --window-size\=1920,1080
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}

    Go To    http://cnn.com

    Capture Page Screenshot
```

In case you want to run in headless mode in a Grid environment use the following example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
Headless Chrome - Create Webdriver2
    ${chrome options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument   --window-size\=1920,1080
    Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_argument   --start-maximized
    Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_argument   --headless
    Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_argument   --disable-gpu
    ${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities      

    Create Webdriver    Remote   command_executor=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub    desired_capabilities=${options}

    Go to     http://cnn.com

    Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: When I tried your code (first variation), it gave me an `unrecognized Chrome version: HeadlessChrome/62.0.3202.94` error.

Comment: Never mind, the problem is with ChromeDriver. 2.29 and below don't support headless chrome.